# MediaRecorder does not produce a valid WebM file

Tags: google-chrome, video, mediarecorder, webm, matroska

`MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported()` returns `true` for 'video/webm', 'video/webm;codecs=avc1', and 'video/webm;codecs=vp9'.

However, only mimeType='video/webm;codecs=vp9' results in a valid webm file ('video/webm;codecs=vp9,opus').

Setting mimeType to either 'video/webm' and 'video/webm;codecs=avc1' results in 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus' file, which is not a valid webm video.

Is this a MediaRecorder bug, Chrome bug or am I missing something?\

Software: Chrome 85, MacOS 10.15. I have not tried this on Windows or Linux.

Comment: I believe this is a Chrome bug, because setting mimeType to 'video/webm' results in 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus' file, which is not a valid webm video.

Comment: It seems this is related https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980822

Answer (score 3):

Reproduction:

```
const wantMimeType = 'video/webm;codecs=h264,opus';
if (MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported(wantMimeType)) {
  let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
    mimeType: wantMimeType,
  });
  // ...drive the recorder
  mediaRecorder.onstop = (event) => {
    try {
      // returns 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus' in Chrome,
      // and the binary file content also says Matroska instead of WebM
      let mimetype = mediaRecorder.mimeType;
      if (!mimeType.startsWith('video/webm')) {
        throw new Error(`We requested "${wantMimeType},
          but the browser gave us "${mediaRecorder.mimeType}"`);
      }
      let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type: mimeType });
      // ...convert to data: URL
      // ...play it in <video src="data:..."> // won't work, if Matroska
    } catch (ex) {
      alert(ex);
    }
  };
}
```

Observations:

1. Chrome responds `true` to `isTypeSupported('video/webm;codecs=h264,opus')`, but Chrome actually does **not** support this combination, i.e. the response is factually incorrect and defeats the entire purpose of `isTypeSupported()`.
2. Chrome ignores the mimetype that we pass in the `MediaRecorder` constructor, and instead returns `video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus`. Which then doesn't work, because `<video>` won't play the Matroska mimetype.

2 solutions:

- Hacky: After recording, just change the mimetype back to `video/webm;codecs=h264,opus`. The file content will still say "Matroska", but `<video>` on Chrome will play it. It's a bad solution, because we're passing in the wrong mimetype, it doesn't match the content. Other software - or Chrome in later versions - might break over it.
- Proper: Don't use H.264, but VP9 or VP8. Chrome supports both, and Firefox supports VP8, and they work properly. As a bonus, they are open, while H.264 is riddled with software patents. Depending on the hardware encoder implementation, VP8/9 also may give better image quality results.

Comment: Just set mimeType: 'video/webm;codecs=VP9'; that is enough!

Answer (score 1):

> `However, only mimeType='video/webm;codecs=vp9' results in a valid webm file.`
> `Is this a MediaRecorder bug, Chrome bug or am I missing something?`

**WebM** is the correct a/v media container for the VP8 and VP9 video codecs.

**AVC1** video codec belongs into an MPEG container (`.mp4`, `.m4v`).
This video codec can also be contained inside an MKV media file (Matroska `.mkv`).

Comment: If that is so, the behavior described above is a Chrome bug, correct?

Comment: It's not a bug, it is correct because those things are supported by Chrome... Google are the creators of VP8 and VP9, so it gives `MediaRecorder.isTypeSupported() = true;` when you query for `codecs=avc1` or `video/webm` but as you can see you cannot put MPEG's AVC1 codec inside competing Google's WebM container and expect to have a valid working file. My answer tells you what codec to use for which container to avoid corrupt files,

Comment: I believe this is a Chrome bug, because setting mimeType to 'video/webm' (codecs not specified) results in 'video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus' file, which is not a valid webm video.

Comment: You must **always specify codecs** for a container. I think H264 is Chrome's default assumed codec (see: _Line 24_ at Chrome's [source code](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:media/base/video_codecs.h;l=24) ).

Comment: What exact problem in your code/app are you trying to solve? Is there anything stopping your app working correctly? There is no bug if things (codecs and containers) are used correctly. Check if a container is supported (MP4, MKV, WebM), then use correct codec(s) for that container (VP8/VP9 is webM, H264 is MKV or MP4).

Comment: "You must always specify codecs"
The codecs are not specified in the example on 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/isTypeSupported

Comment: I had issues because I followed the example on developer.mozilla.org. things worked, but they didn't work well and didn't work cross-platform. I worked around the issues by being more specific in mimeTypes. The major issue was the one outlined above. Thank you for comments on this.